# I can't install web3 because I've an error with rlp

Tags: python, web3py

When I try to install web3 throw pip install web3, I have this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rusty-rlp<0.2,>=0.1.15 (from rlp<=2.0.0.alpha-1,>=1.0.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>
=0.5.3->web3) (from versions: none)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running? And are you installing into a virtual environment? I've just tested with Python 3.8 on Linux into a venv and it worked without any errors.

Comment: Hi, I'm working with windows 10, whit a venv and I tried with Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 but I'have always the same error

Comment: I'm not sure why people are down-voting this. This is a serious issue and the question is valid. I am facing the same issue on a raspberry pi. Tried compiling the latest python3.8.6 from source (took about 4 hours). The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I think PIP can't find a version of the package for Python(32bits). It worked with a 64 bit installation.

Please read my answer here:

[Unable to install web3. I get an error saying version does not satisfy requirement rusty-rlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64164283/unable-to-install-web3-i-get-an-error-saying-version-does-not-satisfy-requireme/64171161#64171161)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be because of the build binaries available for rusty-rlp. There is an issue [HERE](https://github.com/cburgdorf/rusty-rlp/issues/17) and a pull request [HERE](https://github.com/ethereum/pyrlp/pull/127) related to this topic. I assume it won't be possible to install on an ARM machine or x32 till this gets resolved, which I assume won't take too long.

Update:

Now pyrlp is used instead or rusty-rlp for ARM and 32-bit devices. So this error should simply no longer be there if you install web3 now.