# Unable to install web3. I get an error saying version does not satisfy requirement rusty-rlp

Tags: python, web3py

I am trying to install some packages for Python. When installing web3, I get an error saying there is no version that satisfies rusty-rlp. Other packages get installed fine. I am using

pip version: 20.2.3

python version: 3.8.5

OS: Windows 10

IDE: PyCharm Community Edition

```
Collecting web3
  Using cached web3-5.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (467 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from web3) (3.2.0)
Collecting pypiwin32>=223; platform_system == "Windows"
  Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
Collecting lru-dict<2.0.0,>=1.1.6
  Using cached lru-dict-1.1.6.tar.gz (9.4 kB)
Collecting eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3
  Using cached eth_account-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting eth-hash[pycryptodome]<1.0.0,>=0.2.0
  Using cached eth_hash-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting hexbytes<1.0.0,>=0.1.0
  Using cached hexbytes-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 kB)
Collecting ipfshttpclient<1,>=0.4.13
  Using cached ipfshttpclient-0.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (231 kB)
Collecting eth-utils<2.0.0,>=1.9.5
  Using cached eth_utils-1.9.5-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting eth-typing<3.0.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached eth_typing-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from web3) (2.24.0)
Collecting eth-abi<3.0.0,>=2.0.0b6
  Using cached eth_abi-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting websockets<9.0.0,>=8.1.0
  Using cached websockets-8.1-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (65 kB)
Collecting protobuf<4,>=3.10.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (438 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (0.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (20.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from jsonschema<4.0.0,>=3.2.0->web3) (47.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32>=223; platform_system == "Windows"->web3) (228)
Collecting bitarray<1.3.0,>=1.2.1
  Using cached bitarray-1.2.2.tar.gz (48 kB)
Collecting eth-rlp<1,>=0.1.2
  Using cached eth_rlp-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting rlp<=2.0.0.alpha-1,>=1.0.0
  Using cached rlp-2.0.0a1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting eth-keys!=0.3.2,<0.4.0,>=0.2.1
  Using cached eth_keys-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting eth-keyfile<0.6.0,>=0.5.0
  Using cached eth_keyfile-0.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome<4,>=3.6.6; extra == "pycryptodome"
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.9.8-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (14.1 MB)
Collecting multiaddr>=0.0.7
  Using cached multiaddr-0.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting cytoolz<1.0.0,>=0.10.1; implementation_name == "cpython"
  Using cached cytoolz-0.11.0.tar.gz (477 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\johnson lien\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.16.0->web3) (3.0.4)
Collecting parsimonious<0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Using cached parsimonious-0.8.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rusty-rlp<0.2,>=0.1.15 (from rlp<=2.0.0.alpha-1,>=1.0.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for rusty-rlp<0.2,>=0.1.15 (from rlp<=2.0.0.alpha-1,>=1.0.0->eth-account<0.6.0,>=0.5.3->web3)
```

I continue to get this error when trying to install the package on PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

As I was trying to install the rusty-rlp package itself downloading the files from the web, I realized there is no option (wheel or zip file) for 32-bit python installations.

I'm on a 64-bit windows PC but for some reason I had a Python-32bit version running so, I Installed Python38-64bit and ran Pip again and the issue with web3 disappeared.

Comment: I get a similar error when I try pip3 install web3 in Mac OS which has Python 3.9 64-bit installed.

Answer (score -1):

@viken answer is true! But in my case I had to uninstall Python 3.9 and install Python 3.8.7 to be able to install rusty-rlp.